# How to ignore bindings when matching a literal using syntax/parse

Tags: racket

In `syntax-parse` we can use [`~literal`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html?q=syntax%2Fparse#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._~7eliteral%29%29) but this considers bindings. Specifically it "Matches any identifier free-identifier=? to literal-id". I would like to ignore bindings. Specifically, I would like to match any piece of syntax `x` such that `(equal? (syntax-e x) 'some-datum)`. In the example that follows, I would like syntax-parse to succeed even though `bar` has different binding information:

```
#lang racket

(module m racket
  (provide foo)
  (require (for-syntax syntax/parse))
  (define-syntax (foo stx)
    (syntax-parse stx
      [(_ (~literal bar) x)
       #'x])))

(require 'm)

(define bar 1)
(foo bar 2)
```

Is this possible? It seems that `(~literal bar #:phase -999)` works, but I don't know enough about phases to know how reliable this is (or isn't).

Comment: Below `~literal` in the documentation, you should find [`~datum`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html?q=syntax%2Fparse#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._~7edatum%29%29). I think that does exactly what you're describing you're looking for: `(~datum bar)`

Comment: Thanks! How did I miss that? If you add it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Alex Knauth's comment. The correct answer is to use [`~datum`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/stxparse-patterns.html?q=syntax%2Fparse#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Fparse..rkt%29._~7edatum%29%29): "The ~datum form is useful for recognizing identifiers symbolically, in contrast to the ~literal form, which recognizes them by binding."